# 8GB MicroSD as root Linux HDD with data on seperate 1TB drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I currently have a home file server (CentOS 6.3 w/ Samba) that does some simple WWW (Nginx/PHP) right now. The data (shared files as well as WWW data) currently reside on a 1TB HDD and the kernel (user files/logs/configs) resides on an 80GB HDD (both spinning platter).

I'm planning on adding some other functionality to include a database as well as possible user profile store (where I'd keep user files that could get very large). To achieve this I'm planning on keeping my 1TB as my main 'data' store where I'll set my `/home/` directory to as well as store my database files to.

For the kernel side (logs/etc) I was thinking about dropping my 80GB spinning platter and opting for a USB-based 8GB SD card as my root partition (my current `df -h` shows that I'm only using around 2GB for my 'system' drive [the 80GB drive]).

I'm considering this for a couple of reasons to include the following:

1.) Power consumption; granted it's a 'server' and I also have some other larger HDD's attached, but my thought is that 1 less spinning HDD is 1 less spinning HDD

2.) Size, do I really need an 80GB drive JUST to hold the kernel and few programs needed to run?

3.) Kind of linked to 1, but thermal; 1 less spinning HDD also means less thermal issues

4.) Backup. 8GB spares are easier/cheaper to maintain.

But this leads me to a couple of concerns:

1.) Is 8GB enough space for the kernel and logs that could amass from usage of a configuration like I've described? (I only plan on having my kernel/logs/configs/applications on the 8GB drive, no user data or large database files)

2.) Could there be any potential cross drive issues that I might not be aware of? My current configuration doesn't warrant any `chrooting` as of yet, but could very well in the future.

3.) Are any of my points/concerns even valid for the 8GB card over my current 80GB SATA HDD?

I have a suspicion that the only advantage I might realize by using an 8GB SD over spinning platter is simply the thermal issue (which is worth it to me to be honest).

Thanks for any tips with this, and please let me know if I need to edit for clarity.

edit: as a side note the swap will be on the 1TB so as not to kill the SD card.

Comment: If you're going to use a swap partition, you may want to put it on the 1TB drive, since frequent writes will cause the card to wear out faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know on the issue of logs, but you could devise a system to push the older logs onto the 1TB HDD, but you may not even use up the 8GB of space, and if worst comes to worst, you could upgrade to a 16GB MicroSD. Other than that you shouldn't have any other issues since it should act like a typical hard drive.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought of the logs potentially filling up the 8, but I'm building in a sort of monitoring system so it could push the logs if they get too big. Thanks for the info/confirmation!